# How do I make Snap Store fonts on Arch Linux display as text and not as empty rectangles?

Tags: fonts, archlinux, snapcraft

I recently set up a Parallels VM on my Mac with Arch Linux as the OS. I followed [these directions to set up Arch](https://presuppositions.org/software/arch-linux/) (except I didn't install most of the fonts until after everything else was done).

I then installed the [Snapcraft Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-store-app). However, when I open the Snap Store, the fonts for the Snap Store don't show up. Instead of letters, I just see empty rectangles.

[image]

I tried to fix it [using the recommended processes here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/snap-store-font-issue-everything-is-a-rectangle-screenshot/105932/3):

```
sudo rm -v /var/cache/fontconfig/*
fc-cache -r
```

...but those accomplished nothing for me, even after an immediate restart. But even worse than the Snap Store not working, a Snap app that I am creating (which was the whole reason I installed Arch to begin with) also fails to display any font letters on Arch, and just has empty rectangles show up.

Both the Snap Store and also my own Snap app display font letters perfectly fine on my Parallels VMs of Ubuntu, Fedora, and Manjaro. It's just my custom Arch install that won't display them. Also, other apps on my Arch VM that I've installed apart from the Snap Store, like Chromium and Opera, display their font letters correctly with no issues at all.

**How do I make the fonts display?**

Thanks in advance, especially for any answers that give me clear and simple actionable answers instead of just general principles!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with the following commands, run in the terminal:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/fontconfig/*
rm ~/.cache/fontconfig/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Same here
This is the cmd result

```
    14:53:24:0686 Gs  enabled plugins: odrs, rewrite-resource, snap, icons, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
    14:53:24:0686 Gs  disabled plugins: appstream, desktop-categories, desktop-menu-path, dpkg, dummy, epiphany, fedora-pkgdb-collections, generic-updates, hardcoded-blacklist, hardcoded-featured, hardcoded-popular, modalias, os-release, provenance, provenance-license, repos, shell-extensions
    14:53:24:0796 Gs  failed to create an app for */*/*/*/system/*
    14:53:24:0816 Gs  updates-shell: failed to get updates: no plugin could handle get-updates
    14:53:24:0816 Gs  failed to create an app for */*/*/*/system/*
    14:53:24:0816 Gs  failed to get system app
    14:53:24:0816 Gs  failed to convert URL to GsApp: no application was created for running url-to-app with dedupe-flags=7 with refine-flags=require-license,require-url,require-size,require-version,require-history,require-setup-action,require-origin,require-related,require-menu-path,require-allow-packages,require-provenance,require-icon,require-permissions,require-origin-hostname,require-runtime,require-screenshots,require-categories,require-project-group,require-developer-name,require-kudos,content-rating with timeout=60 with search=file:///home/charshell/%25U on plugin=snap
    14:53:24:0817 Gs  Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
    14:53:25:0828 GLib g_path_get_basename: assertion 'file_name != NULL' failed
    14:53:25:0828 GLib g_regex_match_full: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
    14:53:25:0828 GLib g_path_get_basename: assertion 'file_name != NULL' failed
    14:53:25:0828 GLib g_regex_match_full: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
    14:53:26:0019 Gs  hiding category audio-video featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
    14:53:26:0163 Gs  hiding category graphics featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
    14:53:26:0355 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
    14:53:26:0878 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
```